# CSS Layout. Can not get idea how to fix it

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working on a website, which was done by a freelancer some time ago. I can not hire him again and I decided to make changes by myself.
here is the website:
[Site](http://www.crazestation.com/) 
I need to add a page to the website. It's quite a simple task, but when I'm trying to make menu item "Sourcing & Promotional products", it begins to look in the following way:
http://clip2net.com/s/3o7Vef3

I can't attach image to the low rating.
I have no idea about how can I fix it. Maybe you can suggest something.
The css for this item is:

```
 background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 178px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 0px;
```

Comment: Please check [help], [help/on-topic] prior to asking people here to open links to find out about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navi ul li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #303030;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #303030;
    -> change this: width: 178px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px/45px "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    -> remove: padding: 0px 178px 0px 0px;
}
```

Your designer made the width 0px; This way, every letter would go on a new line.
And he made the padding on the left side 178px.
Just remove the `padding`
and make the width 178px

the arrows indicate what needed to be changed

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. I'm not a professional Developer. I just try to do this work by myself, without hiring anybody. I did not noticed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this style to site, it help you

```
#navi ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working nice. I'm just wondering, is any way to add the 2nd line to this link? For example, add "Products"? To look in this way?
http://c2n.me/3o7Y7yL
I tried to use line-height property, but it gives not a proper result.

Comment: add new item to menu? or second line to current menu item

Comment: I'm about new line to current menu item.